# Which VCenter Server Applience 5.5 service should be running on 443/tcp port?

Tags: vmware

I get error 'Connection refused' when try to connect from vSphere Client and web client.
I check output of command netstat -tnpl and not see 443 port in listening ports.
Which VCenter Server Applience 5.5 service should be running on 443/tcp port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to start the service running on port 443. This service is vmware-vpxd:

> $ netstat -tnpl | grep :443
>   tcp        0   0 0.0.0.0:443  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN      4780/vpxd
>   tcp        0   0 :::443       :::*       LISTEN      4780/vpxd

In my case, i got error when vpxd started: "vpxd failed to initialize"
The problem was solved updade VCenter Server Applience,  as described in the article https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2031331

A similar problem was found in the blog:
https://blog.robinfourdeux.com/vcenter-5-1b-waiting-for-vpxd-to-initialize-failed/